# A generalized Jensen's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, inequality

Let $(U , \mu)$ and $(V,\nu)$ be probability spaces. Let $f$ be a convex functional on $L^1(\mu)$, i.e.

$$f(tX + (1-t)Y) \leq t f(X) + (1-t)f(Y)$$

for all random variables $X$ and $Y$ in $L^1(\mu)$. Is there a version of Jensen's inequality for $f$? i.e., can we say that

$$E_\nu f(Z) \geq f(E_\nu (Z) )$$

for sufficiently well-behaved random variables $Z$ on $U\times V$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [conditional Jensen inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting).